# How to get clientId using session object in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I have following code in which i am not able to get the client id of current user, so we did a workaround in which we are bringing all the client which are present for a specific client and checking one by one but instead of that we want to get specific client and use it where RestExampleUserStorageProvider is Constructor.

```
public RestExampleUserStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model, Properties props) {

        this.props = props;
        this.model = model;
        this.session = session;
        System.out.println(session.getContext().getClient())


    }
```